# Cache warming for logged in user roles

Tags: 7, caching

I have 2 pages that are highly customized per user, and I happen to know exactly when certain users are going to log in (this site is used by students during classtime). I have APC and memcache helping, but they are basically worthless here since my users hit these pages once or twice right at the beginning of their session and don't often return, but may spend over 10 seconds waiting for the page to generate when 40 users all log in at once and try to get the different versions of the same page.

I plan on significantly redoing these pages to make them less resource intensive, but for the moment, I'd love to be able to schedule a cron job to do a cache warm 10 minutes before class starts so they have a better experience sooner. Is there any way to do a cache warm for pages that are custom per user when I don't have their password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `drush user-login` together with `curl` (or `wget`) like this:

```
drush --uri=http://your-site.com/drupal-dir-if-any/ user-login --browser=0 username path/to/heavy/site | xargs curl -L
```

The `drush user-login` command prints a one-time login link of the following form:

```
http://your-site.com/drupal-dir-if-any/user/reset/1/1390809497/hzqAmTzHMdBIXDIrkbDsmLIyPQtcDnjAufz9Fd5OUJk/login?destination=path/to/heavy/site
```

Then `xargs` will pick it up from `stdin` and passes it as last command line argument to `curl`. Finally the `-L` flag instructs `curl` to follow redirects. You might want to also supply `-o /dev/null` in order to discard the output of `curl`.

Comment: As far as I know Drupal does not cache pages for logged in users. But some like filtered text may be cached.

Comment: @AgA Drupal can cache for logged-in users, see my answer ;) But you're right, does not do it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you probably should start caching these pages. If you don't know, then you don't cache pages for logged-in users at all.

See [Authcache](https://drupal.org/project/authcache) module:

> The Authcache module offers page caching for both anonymous users and logged-in authenticated users. This allows Drupal/PHP to only spend 1-2 milliseconds serving pages, greatly reducing server resources.
>
> Please note that enabling authenticated user caching will require modifying how your user-customized content displays on your pages. You should be an experienced Drupal developer if you choose to implement the full functionality of this module.

When you will have it, warming mentioned in [znerol's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/101216/16495) will be able to make a significant difference.

Comment: I'm using the Views Per-User-Cache module (https://drupal.org/project/views_puc), which addresses my major pain points. I don't think Authcache would help me in the short term as I'd need to move a lot of custom user content to ajax/ From Authcache: "Please consider your goals and site functionality carefully, as the final HTML of each cached page must be the same for each user role."